# JSF Datatable Map Iteration issue?

Tags: jsf

I have this code in My JSF Page

```
<h:dataTable value="#{announcementBean.monthList}" var="myMapEntry">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{myMapEntry.key}" />
        <h:dataTable value="#{myMapEntry.value}" var="family">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{family.monthName}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

And my data is something like this

```
{2007=[com.kuber.vo.AnnouncementVO@87281f], 2010=[com.kuber.vo.AnnouncementVO@15b4804, com.kuber.vo.AnnouncementVO@1d510be], 2012=[com.kuber.vo.AnnouncementVO@13e49a8]}
```

But the generated HTML page displays nothing. What can be issue in this code?

```
private TreeMap<String, List<AnnouncementVO>> monthList = new TreeMap<String, List<AnnouncementVO>>();

public void fetchMonthList(List<AnnouncementVO> dataList) {
    for (AnnouncementVO announcementVO : dataList) {
        String year = getYearFromDate(announcementVO.getAnnouncementDt());
        if (!monthList.containsKey(year)) {
            ArrayList listRecord = new ArrayList();
            announcementVO.setMonthName(getMonthANDYearFromDate(announcementVO.getAnnouncementDt()));
            listRecord.add(announcementVO);
            monthList.put(year, listRecord);
        } else {
            ArrayList list = (ArrayList) monthList.get(year);
            announcementVO.setMonthName(getMonthANDYearFromDate(announcementVO.getAnnouncementDt()));
            list.add(announcementVO);
            monthList.put(year, list);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your key and value classes used in the `Map` don't override the `toString` method.

Comment: Please stop adding the java tag, it will only result in non-JSF users try to give a non accurate answer.

Comment: Where do you invoke this `fetchMonthList` method?

Comment: Its call from my constructor

Comment: Have you verified this code gets executed before the page gets displayed?

Comment: Yes everything working fine i already post result when i am not using map.key in JSF page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<Entry<String, List<AnnouncementVO>>> getYearList() {
        Set<Entry<String, List<AnnouncementVO>>> yearSet = monthList.entrySet();
        return new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, List<AnnouncementVO>>>(yearSet);
    }
```

Then change jsf code monthList to yearList

```
<h:dataTable value="#{announcementBean.yearList}" var="myMapEntry">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{myMapEntry.key}" />
        <h:dataTable value="#{myMapEntry.value}" var="family">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{family.monthName}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate over a Map inteface using the JSF Datatable. You have two options:

1) Iterate over the TreeMap using the JSTL c:forEach:

```
<c:forEach items="#{announcementBean.monthList}" var="myMapEntry">
        <h:outputText value="#{myMapEntry.key}" />
        <h:dataTable value="#{myMapEntry.value}" var="family">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{family.monthName}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
</c:forEach>
```

2) Use the Entry interface:

```
public List<Entry<String, List<AnnouncementVO>>> getObject() {
   List<Entry<String, List<AnnouncementVO>>> obj = 
              new ArrayList<Entry<String, List<AnnouncementVO>>>();
   obj.addAll(monthList.entrySet());
}
```